# How to compare JComboBox to database value

Tags: java, sql

I am currently doing a payroll system and I am really confused why `access` does not prove true event though the username and password inserted is correct. What happens is I enter the correct username and password and I still get the message dialog "Invalid Input". Meaning `count` is not increased by 1 even though there is a condition. Why is this?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        
        String sql = "select id,username,password,profession from Users where (username =? and password =? and profession =?)";
        
        try{
            
            int count =0;
            
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            pst.setString(1, txt_username.getName());
            pst.setString(2, txt_password.getName());
            pst.setString(3, txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
         
            
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                Emp.empId = id;  
                
            }
            String access = (txt_combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
            

            
            if(access == "Admin"){ 
                System.out.print(count);
            }    
                if(count == 1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                    MainMenu j = new MainMenu();
                    j.setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();

                    

                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input");
                    
                    
                }
```

Comment: Where are you incrementing count?

Answer (score 0):

You can do count directly in your SQL. But counting is not very good way. But I see you try to use ID of selected record. And its wrong way.

I suggest you try reduce SQL:

`select id from Users where (username=? and password=? and profession=?)`

Then change next lines:

```
            while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                Emp.empId = id;  
            }
```

to

```
            int count = 0;
            if(rs.next()){
                Emp.empId = rs.getInt(1);
                count++;
            }
```